# robocopy parameter /bytes doesn't work

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I just installed `robocopy` because I wasn't able to deal with a lot of files which had a too long fullname. I used [this tutorial](http://learn-powershell.net/2013/04/01/list-all-files-regardless-of-260-character-path-restriction-using-powershell-and-robocopy/) to learn about `robocopy`. This site explains pretty much everything I need, but I can't make it work, even by copying commands line by line.
My first problem is the first indicated command on the tutorial:

```
robocopy .\PowerShellScripts NULL /L /S /NJH /BYTES /FP /NC /NDL /XJ /TS /R:0 /W:0
```

I switch `.\PowerShellScripts` to `C:` and it crashes, telling me the 6th parameter (`/bytes`) is invalid.

```
Simple usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR
```

But I checked on other sites and `/bytes` does exist, and I need it to work. By the way, it works if I remove it.

I don't really understand the second command but it is about mount points and I don't have some.
Then, when I launch the third command:

```
$item = "PowerShellScripts"
$params = New-Object System.Collections.Arraylist
$params.AddRange(@("/L","/S","/NJH","/BYTES","/FP","/NC","/NDL","/TS","/XJ","/R:0","/W:0"))
$countPattern = "^\s{3}Files\s:\s+(?<Count>\d+).*"
$sizePattern = "^\s{3}Bytes\s:\s+(?<Size>\d+(?:\.?\d+)\s[a-z]?).*"
((robocopy $item NULL $params)) | ForEach {
    If ($_ -match "(?<Size>\d+)\s(?<Date>\S+\s\S+)\s+(?<FullName>.*)") {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            FullName = $matches.FullName
            Size = $matches.Size
            Date = [datetime]$matches.Date
        }
    } Else {
        Write-Verbose ("{0}" -f $_)
    }
}
```

I can launch the command, but nothing is written. Does someone know about that?

Comment: What do you mean you "installed robocopy"? The program comes with the operating system and should already be present. Did you download some ancient version that doesn't support the `/bytes` parameter? Check the output of `robocopy /?`.

Comment: Well I'm on WinXP, I guess Robocopy wasnt on every computer yet ? Seems like the version I have actually doesnt support `\bytes` ... Does it mean I cant deal with that as long as I work on XP ?

Comment: Windows XP is out of support for more than a year now. And yes, the `robocopy` version from the Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools package doesn't provide a `/bytes` parameter.